# how to control the user relogin

Tags: session

If one user have login in one computer or a browser,then he login in another computer/browser again,so the former login should be marked as invalid,is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way it to set a cookie with a session id when they log in, and record the latest session id somewhere server-side (like a database) keyed by that user id.  On any website access, verify it's the latest session for that user.

Comment: So how to make the former session invalid?

Comment: Are you asking how to specifically invalidate their cookie?  It really depends on what software you're running on the server & how you have access setup on the server.

Comment: Do a session check on every call. If cookie.client_uuid == user.last_uuid, execute as normal. else delete cookie.